# NuGet API call to get the latest version number of a package

Tags: api, nuget, proget

I have a test harness, in which I would like to verify the version number of a nuget package automatically.

I have been searching for a good while trying to find a way to get the latest version **number** (not the latest package) for a given package.  But no luck.

**Is there a way to get the latest version number of a package via an API?**  (Needs to be automatable).

If it matters, I am using ProGet for my NuGet repository.

Answer (score 2):

This url template will get you the package info (in XML) of the latest version.  You will then have to parse out the LatestVersion or AbosluteLatestVersion:

```
$"https://{yourNuGetRepositoryBaseUrl}/nuget/{feedName}/Packages()?$filter=Id%20eq%20%27{packageId}%27%20and%20IsLatestVersion&$top=1"
```

Note that this works with ProGet (that has many different feeds).  You could probably omit the FeedName part to use it with NuGet.org.